# Equivalence of branched covers of the Riemann sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

Consider the functions $f(z)=z^4$ and $g(z)=z^4+1$, branched covers of $S^2$. These functions have the same branch data, so they should be equivalent in some way. In what way are they equivalent?

Comment: Having the same branch data is in itself an equivalence relation. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Sure, but there should be some function $h$ of a certain type so that $g\circ h=f$ or something.

Answer (score 1):

Say that $f$ and $g$ equivalent, if for two (holomorphic) homeomorphisms $h_1,h_2:\mathbb CP^1\to\mathbb CP^1$ satisfied $h_2\circ f\circ h_1=g$. Maybe, in this sense?